# Full access Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-android-api

For Google Drive API, the drive.file scope seems to give only access to the files created by the app. Is there a scope for Google Drive that gives access to the entire drive? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this scope :

[Google Drive](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive)

This will bring Full permissive scope to access all of a user's files

Comment: Could you please tell me how to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth#what_scope_or_scopes_does_my_app_need). Full access to all files in the user's Drive (`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`) may be necessary for some apps. An app designed to sync files, for instance, needs this level of access to Drive. Apps with special needs related to listing or reorganizing files might need full scope.

Check the sample code in this [GitHub page](https://github.com/redjio/SSApk/blob/256353d94ad24876fb4d6de048c31e33b19f847f/com/google/api/services/drive/DriveScopes.java).